# Reading .xlsx file iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, afnetworking, xlsx

I am trying to download .xlsx file from server using AFNetworking. But it gives me error saying:

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/zip" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/zip

It shows whole response inside the NSError.

I don't want to use any third party library as I am integrating this in my SDK itself.

Comment: It looks like you haven't set the accepts header to include application/zip

Comment: Thanks for replying @Paulw11. I am sending request as a NSMutableRequest. by printing header, it shows me {
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    "User-Agent" = "xyz-snippets/2.0 (iPhone; iOS 11.2; Scale/3.00)";
}

Comment: I have also tried answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32014667/4685283. but no luck.

Comment: Are you trying to get a json or application/zip from your URL ? Your request is in json format

Comment: it is returning direct xlsx file.

Comment: @PriyankaMistry Please try same solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014588/afnetworking-occasionally-get-unacceptable-content-type-application-json-on/32014667#32014667 but this time add "application/zip" in array.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for replying late as I was assigned to some other task. @AnKit I have tried adding "application/zip" in array but it returns unsupported type

Comment: It returns me "PK
h.8L֒|ZZdocProps/core.xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>" this kind of response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Download .xlsx file in AFNetworking2.x. You can't use this code. This code is for Json Serialization. 
**Reason**:

```
/* 
In AFURLResponseSerialization.m this line will convert downloaded data to json, which make invalid serialization error 
*/
    responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:self.readingOptions error:&serializationError];
```

**NOT Working Code** :

```
    // This code will not work for XLSX File
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];

        [manager GET:@"Link to xlsx File" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

**Use this** :

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/2.x#creating-a-download-task

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Link to xlsx File"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: It's working :) with some modification from code side. Thank you so much

Comment: @PriyankaMistry Welcome :)